# Shiny bslib() and Datatables inside a Bootstrap Card

Tags: css, r, bootstrap-4, shiny

I like the design option of putting things inside a card like the reproducible example here taken from the blslib() [website](https://rstudio.github.io/bslib/articles/utility-classes.html). This does not render on my screen as expected. There should be 10 rows visible and this, on my screen, renders two rows with a scroll bar. I thought the argument fillContainer would cause for this to render and fill the card space.

Can anyone see a fix so that the table fills the card with the number of rows set by the page length option?

```
bs4_card <- function(body, title) {
  div(class="table-responsive",
    class = "card",
    div(class = "card-header bg-primary", title),
    div(class = "card-body d-flex justify-content-center", body)
  )
}

shinyApp(
  fluidPage(
    theme = bslib::bs_theme(primary = "orange"),
    uiOutput("dat")
  ),
  function(input, output) {
    output$dat <- renderUI({
      table <- DT::datatable(mtcars, fillContainer = TRUE, style = "bootstrap4", rownames = FALSE)
      bs4_card(table, "The mtcars dataset")
    })
  }
)
```

**EDIT:**
I have found that if I add `class="table-responsive"` as in my edit to my original post, the number of rows reflects the pagination. Changing the pagination also works and there is a scroll bar added.

My preference, however, is for the card size to grow in relationship to the number of rows in the table instead of having the scroll bar.

I suppose there is a class for this, but am at the limit of my css knowledge here.

Comment: seems to be caused by `fillContainer = TRUE`,...remove it and you will see 10 rows. Might expand the container though,...

Comment: @TonioLiebrand, yes indeed. When I do that the table overflows outside the card, but does show the number of expected rows.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To fit the card size to the table size, you can add `height = "100%"` in `DT::datatable()`, as below:

```r
DT::datatable(mtcars, style = "bootstrap4", rownames = FALSE, height = "100%")
```

Note that you also need to remove `fillContainer = TRUE`.

Answer (score 0):

I know this may be kinda late and I am not sure if this will fix the issue for you.

There is a function in DataTables to readjust the layout after changes or when using in the table in bootstrap tabs.

https://datatables.net/reference/api/columns.adjust()

```
var table = $('#example').DataTable();

$('#container').css( 'display', 'block' );
table.columns.adjust().draw();
```